# Java - JFrame not displaying ImageIcon

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, jframe

```
public Vue(String title) {
    super(title);



    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    JPanel p1 = createPanel1();
    this.getContentPane().add(p1);
    JPanel p2bis = createPanel2bis();
    this.getContentPane().add(p2bis);
    JPanel p3 = createPanel3();
    this.getContentPane().add(p3);




    this.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,400));
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);


    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("voile.png"));
    this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
    System.out.println(image.getDescription());

}
```

Hi,

I spent time to find the solution to display my image as a JFrame icon image...
And tryed a lot of things like

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Constants.LOGO_ABSOLUTE_PATH);
this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
System.out.println(image.getDescription());
```

I put "voile.png" file everywhere in my directories : root,src,bin and inside bin and src packages. I also tryed with an online logo and its URI.

However, it actually doesn't work.
If anyone can help me ?

I'm running it on Eclipse Oxygen and Windows 10

PS : System.out.println(image.getDescription()); always showing a path where my image is located (Anyway I put it everywhere)

Comment: What's the value of `Constants.LOGO_ABSOLUTE_PATH`?

Comment: I tried 
"voile.png"
"https://mywebsite.com/img/voile.png" it exists
and absolute paths like "U:\activities\log AT\myapp\src\Vue\voile.png" "U:\activities\log AT\myapp\voile.png" . I also tryed to double backslash in order to escape \ but nothing good is happening

Comment: Try `/voile.png` with the file in the `src` folder.

Comment: `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Constants.LOGO_ABSOLUTE_PATH);
this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
System.out.println(image.getDescription());`
and
`public static final String LOGO_ABSOLUTE_PATH = "/voile.png";` in constants class
doesn't work
It prints "/voile.png" in eclipse console

Comment: How about `this.setIconImage(image.getImage());this.setVisible(true);`?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore

Comment: *"It doesn't work anymore"* What doesn't work any more? Tip: Add @apemanzilla (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

ImageIcon doesn't support PNG transparency. I had to create a blank jpg image and put logo inside. 
My final code is

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Constants.LOGO);
this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

Comment: *"ImageIcon doesn't support PNG transparency."* Of course it does! See the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) which uses 5 (image icons in 5) labels & 4 buttons to display sub-images of a PNG image [seen in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). The PNG in the question is simply embedded in the web page, with the default white BG color of SO. The PNG once sub-divided and displayed by the code, has a black background color provided by the panel that lays out the buttons and labels.